# If $Y$ is a dense linear subspace of a normed space $X$, how to show $B_Y$ is dense in $B_X$.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a proper dense linear subspace of $X$. Let $B_Y$ be the closed unit ball of $Y$ and $B_X$ be the closed unit ball of $X$. Then how to show $B_Y$ is dense in $B_X$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in B_X$ and let $y_n\to x$ with $y_n\in Y$. Then, $\lVert y_n\rVert\to \lVert x\rVert$. If $\lVert x\rVert<1$, then $y_n$ is eventually in $B_Y$ by the previous remark. If $\lVert x\rVert=1$, then $\frac{1}{\lVert y_n\rVert} y_n\to x$ and $\frac1{\lVert y_n\rVert}y_n\in B_Y$ because $\left\lVert\frac1{\lVert y_n\rVert}y_n\right\rVert=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't get why we need to talk about $\|x\|=1$ and $\|x\|<1$ separately? Can we get $\|y_n\|\leq 1$ from $\|y_n\|\rightarrow \|x\|$?

Comment: I guess you could consider $\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert y_n\rVert}y_n$, in which case you might want to spend a couple of words for sequences that are frequently $0$ when $x=0$. You'd be manipulating algebraically a  sequence that already works, which aestetically sounds weird, but the argument is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am using the sequential definition of dense.

If $Y$ is dense in $X$, that means that for all $x \in X$ there exists $\{y_k\} \in Y$ such that $y_k \rightarrow x$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Then to show your claim
Let $x \in B_X$ then by definition there exists $\{y_k\} \in Y$ such that $y_k \rightarrow x$. Note that due to that there exists a subsequence $y_{kj} \in B_X$ that has that same property ie $y_{kj} \rightarrow x$. Now you also know that $ B_T\subset B_X$ therefore you have that there exists $y_{kj} \in B_Y$ that converges to $x$. This way you avoid using normalization arguments.

Comment: I don't see why you claim to be allowed to find a *subsequence* of norm $\le 1$. For all you know, since $\overline{\{x\in X\,:\, x>1\}}=\{x\in X\,:\, x\ge 1\}$, all the $y_k$-s in the sequence you are considering could have norm strictly larger than $1$.

Comment: Because $y_k \rightarrow x$ after some integer $N$ (cut the tail) there will be all members of the sequence will be in $B_X$, and if they are in $B_X$ then by definition they must have norm one. But you are right I am picking a very special sub-sequence (consisting only of elements close to x) that is close to $x$

Comment: Let's say $X=\ell^2$, $Y=c_{00}$ and $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k/2}e_k$; notice that $\lVert x\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}}=1$, so $x\in B_X$. Since you are the unluckiest person in the universe, you've chosen the sequence $y_n=9\cdot2^{-n/2}e_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2^{-k/2}e_k$. Then, $$\left\lVert y_n-x\right\rVert=\left\lVert 8\cdot 2^{-n/2}e_n-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k/2}e_k\right\rVert=\sqrt{65\cdot 2^{-n}}\to 0$$ and yet $$\lVert y_n\rVert=\sqrt{80\cdot 2^{-n}+\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}}=\sqrt{1+79\cdot 2^{-n}}>1.$$ So you can't find any subsequence in $B_X$ at all.

Comment: This is a good counter example, thank you for showing it to me.